# saving file to phone documents using codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am zipping the app files and I want to save it to the phone documents in iOS. How I can achieve this using root_type_mainstorage in codenameone?

I am struggling with this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shared storage in iOS so I'm not sure what you are trying to do. This will write a file to the file system in iOS. Notice I'm assuming that you have this line in the import:

```
import static com.codename1.ui.CN.*;
```

You can then do:

```
String fileName = getAppHomePath() + "MyFileName.txt";
try(OutputStream os = openFileOutputStream(fileName)) {
    os.write(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
} catch(IOException err) {
    Log.e(err);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Shai. yes I used the same technique and I used cn1lib for zipping the file. But now I want to save the zip file to documents of iOS device like we save in downloads folder of android device.How to achieve this functionality in iOS?

Comment: There is no public downloads directory I'm aware of in iOS. This is an Android feature